# NotificationServiceExtension not called

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, ios-extensions

After iOS 10 released, I use `NotificationServiceExtension` for image notification. It works fine.
But I found something wrong recently.

**Codes in UNNotificationServiceExtension not call anymore.**

I'm not sure the cause so I create a new project for test.
Unfortunately the new project not work neither.

I found something strange：
Run extension in my device, locked screen, then push notification.
Xcode raises this message(Extension is called obviously), unlocked and Xcode print "**Program ended with exit code: 0**".

[image]

Here is my payload:

```
{"aps" : {
        "alert" : {
            "title" : "Introduction To Notification",
            "subtitle" : "Session 707",
            "body" : "New Notification Look Amazing"
        },
       "sound" : "default",
        "category" : "message",
        "badge" : 1,
        "mutable-content": 1
    },
    "attachment-url": "https://api.buienradar.nl/Image/1.0/RadarMapNL"
}
```

Comment: I saw this issue also several times with the new Xcode 9. Just try to run the app via Xcode -> run it with debugger mode -> lock your phone (without stopping your code execution in Xcode) -> send your push ... the push should then work

Comment: Hi .
did you solved this ?